# Rust lifetime confusion with custom clone function

Tags: rust

I think there is a subtle issue with what I'm trying to do here but I can't quite figure out why. I am attempting to clone a Box type (I know the type inside) but I think the lifetime is being propagated out somehow.

```
struct Thing 
{
    internal:Box<dyn std::any::Any>
}

impl Thing 
{
    fn new<T:'static>(u:usize) -> Self 
    {
        return Self 
        {
            internal:Box::new(u)
        }
    } 
    fn clone_func<T:'static>(&self) -> Self
    {
        return Self 
        {
            internal:Box::new(self.internal.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap().clone())
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() 
{
    let a = Thing::new::<usize>(12usize);
    let b = a.clone_func::<usize>();
}
```

Error

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> <source>:19:45
   |
15 |     fn clone_func<T:'static>(&self) -> Self
   |                              ----- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
...
19 |             internal:Box::new(self.internal.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap().clone())
   |                      -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^------------------------- ...is captured and required to live as long as `'static` here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't request `T` to be `Clone`, so when you called `self.internal.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap().clone()`, you actually cloned the *reference*, and tried to box it<sup>1</sup>.

Boxing `&T` works as far as the types are concerned (because it's a `Box<dyn Any>`), but it fails borrow checking. While `T` is guaranteed not to contain references to non-static data, the `&T` refers to the data inside `&self` which is not `'static`, but has the anonymous lifetime of `&self`. This is actually pointed out by the compiler, but the error doesn't make sense without context.

Simply changing the trait bound to `T: Clone + 'static` makes the example compile:

```
fn clone_func<T: Clone + 'static>(&self) -> Self {
    return Self {
        internal: Box::new(self.internal.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap().clone()),
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8b03406c378a8f82d81bce5c112a4e44)

---

<sup>1</sup>
A shared reference is `Clone` and `Copy` because once you have one, you're allowed to create more references to the same data. Normally, given a `foo: &T` and a `T: Clone`, `foo.clone()` will resolve to `T::clone(foo)`, which returns a `T` as expected. But if `T` isn't `Clone`, `foo.clone()` resolves to `<&T>::clone(&foo)`, which returns another `&T` referring to the same `T` value as `foo`, i.e. it "clones" `foo` itself rather than the intended `*foo`.

For example, in this snippet, the type of `b.clone()` is `&X`, not `X` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e7642f167833111931b33423af104cf8)):

```
//#[derive(Clone)]
struct X;

fn main() {
    let a = X;
    let b = &a;
    let () = b.clone();  // note type of b.clone() is &X, not X
}
```

If you uncomment `#[derive(Clone)]`, the type of `b.clone()` becomes the expected `X`.

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Incidentally that is why using UFCS and the target type explicitly e.g. `Arc::clone` or `T::clone` can be useful. Here it would immediately have told you that `T` doesn't implement `Clone`, which is still a bit confusing but less so, and does provide an actual useful suggestion (adding a `Clone` bound).

Comment: @Masklinn I can kind of agree for `Arc::clone()`, but invoking every `clone` as `T::clone(&foo)` instead of `foo.clone()` is not idiomatic Rust and (to me) looks overly verbose and unappealing.